# Dynamic action name based on place where it is triggered from

Tags: ngxs

is it possible for better debugging to make the action name dynamic? for example, I have an action to add an item into the cart, but it can be triggered by multiple buttons. I want to know what button started this action. This store is also shared across the whole application.

Or do you have some other recommendations on how to achieve it?

Thank you for your help.